# Error: Please make sure that "Alexa Skills Kit" is selected for the event source type of arn

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Am new to Alexa development. When configuring alexa in amazon developer site am getting Error:

Error: Please make sure that "Alexa Skills Kit" is selected for the event source type of arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:431036771207:function:HelloWorld?

What am missing here ?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the AWS Lambda console
2. Open your lambda function
3. Add a trigger of the type Alexa Skills Kit and configure it